# Checkdisk is stalling partway through a scan

Tags: windows-vista, hard-drive, chkdsk

In Vista, when I run checkdisk at boot, it consistently stalls at 60%.  I have tried running it three times.  I now have a new second hard drive that is a clone of the original problematic drive.  Checkdisk runs fine on the new HD, so I know it is not some software issue.

Is this stalling an issue?  Is there a fix?

The original drive still works fine, I got the second drive because the original was getting full.

Comment: You never stated if you set chkdsk f or r to run.

Answer (score 2):

Chkdsk can in some cases take hours. Boot, and let it run overnight before taking any other action. There are [reports](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/719963-solved-chkdsk-wont-complete-checking.html) of it taking 24 hours to complete.

It chkdsk still stalls, download the diagnostic tool from your hard drive manufacturer's web page and run it instead of chkdsk. If it completes, try chkdsk at boot again.

Comment: +1 I have personally seen chkdsk take overnight to finish running on a friend's computer with exactly the same symptoms the OP is describing.